# Check if track is available in current country

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm looking for a way to check if a track is available in the users country or not.

The problem is, my 3rd party app will be worldwide and so it's possible that users send tracks as attachment which aren't playable in their country.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Spotify Web-API and its lookup functionality.

You can read the full documentation here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/lookup/

If you request `trackdetail` on a track you will get a response looking something like this.

```
...
<availability>
    <territories>AD AE AF AG AL AM AN AO AR AS AT AU AW AZ BA</territories>
</availability>
...
```

There you have all the country codes where the track is available, then it's up to your app to loop through them or whatever.